# Bicubic Interpolation on Scattered Data in Matlab

Tags: matlab, interpolation, bicubic

I was wondering if there is a way to do bicubic interpolation on a scattered data set (2d)? I did some online searches and figured out that bicubic patches (not sure what these are) need to be fitted on scattered data. Not sure how to proceed from here. Any help will be appreciated!

Note: I understand that Matlab recommends `TriScatteredInterp` and `griddata` to interpolate on scattered points. However, `TriScatteredInterp` is a triangulation interpolation and does not uses splines to interpolate the data.

The data which I have looks something like this (x, y, val):

```
x = [0 0 0 0 0.28 0.28 0.28 0.28 -0.28 0.28 -0.28 -0.28 -0.988 -0.988 -0.988 -0.988 -0.708 -0.708 -0.708 -0.708 -1.268 -1.268 -1.268 -1.268 0.988 0.988 0.988 0.988 1.268 1.268 1.268 1.268 0.708 0.708 0.708 0.708]

y = [0.9993 0.8113 0.6233 0.4353 0.9373 0.7493 0.5613 0.3733 0.8733 0.6853 0.4973 0.3093 0.9993 0.8113 0.6233 0.4353 0.9373 0.7493 0.5613 0.3733 0.8733 0.6853 0.4973 0.3093 0.9993 0.8113 0.6233 0.4353 0.9373 0.7493 0.5613 0.3733 0.8733 0.6853 0.4973 0.3093]

val = [0.25 0.35 0.19 0.14 0.19 -0.45 -0.96 0.61 0.19 0.20 0.22 0.38 0.15 0.51 0.53 0.68 0.36 0.21 0.52 0.70 0.14 0.34 0.45 0.63 0.25 0.40 0.76 0.65 0.82 0.37 0.49 0.57 0.10 0.11 0.61 0.65]
```

Thanks!! Prakhar

Comment: When they say patches they mean small pieces that stick together. What they seem to propose is to make some smaller bicubic interpolations and stick one to each other.

Comment: See this question, it might have what you're looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13898828/bicubic-interpolation-of-3d-surface

Comment: As *bicubic interpolation* needs a regular 2D-grid, there is no such thing as *bicubic interpolation on scattered data*. There might however be other approaches depending on what is really your goal. (As in: I need an interpolation of the surface that is smoother than *C^0*) The next best thing would be to triangulate your `x-y` coordinates and use piecewise cubic splines to approximate the function.